# spark dataframe reducebykey (with non-unique key values) and custom value operation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the code with Spark 1.5.0.

case class myCaseClass(user_id: String, description: String)

Here is my UDF

```
val getConcatenated = udf( (first: String, second: String, third: String) => { first + " " + second + " " + third} )
```

Here is where I generate my dataframe

```
val df_description =  df.withColumn("description",getConcatenated(col("text1"), col("text2"), col("weight"))).select("user_id","description")
```

Now, I want to do a redueByKey operation on this DF which has tow columns (both are strings). My user_ids are not unique and I want to concat all values/description entries for a given user_id.

How can I achieve that?

I can do something like this:

```
 val description_rdd = df_description.map(row => myCaseClass(row.getString(0), row.getString(1)))
```

But how do I generate a pairedrdd here? I then want to swtich back to dataframe by using CreateDataFrame method on rdd.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will create DF with your key column and a column holding a sequence of your descriptions:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

val pairRDD : PairRDDFunctions[String, String] = df_description.rdd.map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getString(1)))
val groupedRDD = pairRDD.groupByKey().map(p => (p._1, p._2.toSeq))
val groupedDF = groupedRDD.toDF()
```